# About the label.text and the null object

Tags: apache-flex

I had make a statment like this

> ```
>           normaluser.user_idUser
>               = parseInt(idUserInput.text);
> ```

and the value of the variable is form here

```
            <s:FormItem width="232" label="User ID">
                <s:TextInput id="idUserInput" text="@{UIt.user_idUser}"/>
            </s:FormItem>
```

Assume "idUserInput" always have value, but why every time I run to the statment the same bug show up

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at userDetailComp/update()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\userDetailComp.mxml:68]
    at userDetailComp/__updateButton_click()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\userDetailComp.mxml:230]

ps. line 68 is the statment "parseInt(idUserInput.text);"
and
line 230 is the click handler

> ```
>         click="update(event)"/>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out where the problem is.
When I use the data binding in the textinput, the textinput's text porperty cannot be access. Dont know why, =.=', but when I change parseInt(idUserInput.text); to parseInt(UIt.user_idUser); which is data binded variable. Everything works fine.